# The meaning of functor $M \mapsto \mbox{Hom}_A(P,M)$ being exact

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

(I'm currently studying Lang's text *Algebra* and it comes up on the page 137. Lang does not explicitly define this expression.)

Is the following understanding correct?

The function  $M \mapsto \mbox{Hom}_A(P,M)$ is called exact if the following holds:
A sequence 
$$
0 \to M' \to M \to M''
$$
is exact if and only if (should I take out one of if and only if?)
$$
0 \to \mbox{Hom}_A(P,M') \to \mbox{Hom}_A(P,M) \to \mbox{Hom}_A(P,M'')
$$.

Here we are dealing with modules and as you may already know, if the above most condition holds then $P$ is projective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functor $\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}M\mapsto\Hom_A(P,M)$ is left exact for any module $P$; this means that from exactness of
$$
0\to M'\to M\to M''
$$
you can always deduce exactness of
$$
0\to\Hom_A(P,M')\to\Hom_A(P,M)\to\Hom_A(P,M'')
$$
The converse implication need not hold when $P$ is a projective module; indeed, the zero module is projective, so if your claim would be true, then *any* sequence of the form $0\to M'\to M\to M''$ would be exact, because
$$
0\to\Hom_A(0,M')\to\Hom_A(0,M)\to\Hom_A(0,M'')
$$
is obviously exact.

Comment: Please let me check and clarify the def. once more: So $P$ is called projective if the exactness of $0\to M' \to M \to M''$ implies the exactness of the induced sequence, right?

Comment: @julypraise No, $P$ is projective if the exactness of $0\to M'\to M\to M''\to 0$ implies the exactness of the induced sequence. You ***need*** the trailing $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should remove the "only if".
Now, for the sequences, you need to add another zero to the right hand side, so it reads:
$$0 \rightarrow {M}' \rightarrow M \rightarrow {M}'' \rightarrow 0$$ which is then sent to $$0 \rightarrow Hom_A(P,{M})' \rightarrow Hom_A(P,M) \rightarrow Hom_A(P,{M}'') \rightarrow 0$$
As you put it, the functor is called left-exact, and if there were a single zero on the right, it would be right exact.